# Validating Server Response

Tags: rest

I have written a REST API and a c# program.

how do i validate that the response is real, and from my server.

SCENARIO: i distribute a freeware to a certain community, which will then require them to register in order to continue.

currently upon logging in, the rest api reply with a JSON `{status:"true" user_data: [...]}`. (i added a login, so i could control who can use the said application)

at the back of my mind a person could setup a fake hostname, and forward traffic to a local webserver to intercept the data and reply the JSON. how do i prevent this?

Comment: It is unclear what help you need. Can you elaborate your scenario and what could go wrong in your view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer: you can't.**

If it is on the client there is no way you can avoid this scenario if the 'attacker' is dedicated. There is simply no way you can 'force' your application to talk only to your server as the user can intercept and tamper with the communication, forcing it to other servers and returning canned responses.

You could make it harder for them by using a number of techniques to secure the communication between server and client: use SSL/TLS, encrypt communication between the applications with public/private key encryption, and so on.

But if your 'attacker' is dedicated, forget it. Just look at games such as Diablo III and SimCity. They required persistent connections and have very smart people writing loads of code, yet these games are often cracked within days of the release. And even if your communication is 100% foolproof, popping open the EXE with a hex editor and tampering with it works just as well.